# Assign a the value of a sparse matrix to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sparse-matrix

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as scsp
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix,lil_matrix

# create an empty numpy matrix
wi=np.empty((num_clusters*num_cluster_neurons, input))   
for i in range(num_clusters*num_cluster_neurons):         
    temp_neuron_prob=dic_cluster_prob[dic_neuron_cluster[i]]

    #create 1*input shape sparse matrix according to probability
    lil=lil_matrix(scsp.rand(1, input, temp_neuron_prob))

    #want to assign the 1*input sparse matrix to one slice of the numpy matrix
    wi[i,:]=lil[:]
```

I tried to assign the value of a lil_matrix to one slice of numpy array, but it gives the error 'setting an array element with a sequence'

I want to know why comes this error because they have the same size and how could I do to improve efficiency, since numpy array is faster than sparse matrix(lil_matrix).

**I want to use numpy array to have the values created by the sparse matrix**

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sparse matrix is not an array subclass (like `np.matrix`), and doesn't necessarily behave like one either (though in many ways it does try to).

```
In [129]: arr = np.zeros((3,4),int)
In [130]: M = sparse.lil_matrix([0,1,2,0])
In [131]: M.shape
Out[131]: (1, 4)
In [132]: arr[0,:] = M
...
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

But if I first convert the sparse matrix to an array or matrix, the assignment works:

```
In [133]: arr[0,:] = M.A
In [134]: arr[0,:] = M.todense()
In [135]: arr
Out[135]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

As a general rule, sparse matrices can't be plugged into `numpy` code.  The exception is when `numpy` code that delegates the task to the objects own methods.

Looks like you are trying to generate something like:

```
In [148]: arr = np.zeros((3,5),float)
In [149]: for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
     ...:     arr[i,:] = sparse.rand(1,5, .2*(i+1)).A
     ...:     
In [150]: arr
Out[150]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.82470353,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.43339367,  0.99427277,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.99843277,  0.05182824,  0.1705916 ,  0.        ]])
```

A pure sparse equivalent might be:

```
In [151]: alist = []
In [152]: for i in range(3):
     ...:     alist.append(sparse.rand(1,5, .2*(i+1)))
     ...:     
     ...:     
In [153]: alist
Out[153]: 
[<1x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in COOrdinate format>,
 <1x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in COOrdinate format>,
 <1x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>]
In [154]: sparse.vstack(alist)
Out[154]: 
<3x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [155]: _.A
Out[155]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.19028467,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.92668274,  0.67424419],
       [ 0.96208905,  0.63604635,  0.        ,  0.69463657,  0.        ]])
```

But considering that `sparse.vstack` uses sparse `bmat` to join the matrices into a new one, and `bmat` combines the `coo` attributes of the components, the dense array accumulation approach could well be faster.

Comment: Your answer just perfectly helped me understand some concepts of the use of sparse matrix, Thank you a lot!