# TypeError: SparseArray does not support item assignment via setitem

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix

Given:

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__) # '2.1.0'
df=pd.DataFrame([[1., 0., 1.5], [0., 2., 0.]], dtype=pd.SparseDtype("float32"))
```

I'd like to assign custom values in my sliced pandas sparse dataframe, so I do the following:

```
df_sliced=df.iloc[0].copy() # OK
df_sliced.iloc[:]=0 # ERROR
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/CSC_CONTAINER/miniconda/envs/env1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 885, in __setitem__
    iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value, self.name)
  File "/CSC_CONTAINER/miniconda/envs/env1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1895, in _setitem_with_indexer
    self._setitem_single_block(indexer, value, name)
  File "/CSC_CONTAINER/miniconda/envs/env1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2138, in _setitem_single_block
    self.obj._mgr = self.obj._mgr.setitem(indexer=indexer, value=value)
  File "/CSC_CONTAINER/miniconda/envs/env1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 399, in setitem
    return self.apply("setitem", indexer=indexer, value=value)
  File "/CSC_CONTAINER/miniconda/envs/env1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 354, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "/CSC_CONTAINER/miniconda/envs/env1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 1758, in setitem
    values[indexer] = value
  File "/CSC_CONTAINER/miniconda/envs/env1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/sparse/array.py", line 583, in __setitem__
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: SparseArray does not support item assignment via setitem
```

What's an efficient way (workaround) to assign values in `SparseDtype` in Pandas?

Comment: It's not possible: [Assign a the value of a sparse matrix to numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48146072/15239951)

Comment: @Corralien, your link is about `scipy.sparse`.  Here it's the (cutrrent) pandas version of SparseArray.  Still I'm not surprised that there indexing limitations in the pandas version.

Answer (score 0):

The error traceback with more context is:

```
SparseArray.__setitem__(self, key, value)
    581 def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    582     # I suppose we could allow setting of non-fill_value elements.
    583     # TODO(SparseArray.__setitem__): remove special cases in
    584     # ExtensionBlock.where
    585     msg = "SparseArray does not support item assignment via setitem"
--> 586     raise TypeError(msg)
```

This tells me that `SparseArray` is still under development, and that, for now, setting values, is not working.  I know, from working with `scipy.sparse`, that setting sparse values takes more work, especially if `fill` values might be changed to non-fill.

`scipy.sparse.coo_matrix` format doesn't implement indexing at all - get or set.  `csr_matrix`, which is used for most calculations, does implement indexing, but gives an efficiency warning with the `set`.  Potentially `set` can change the 'sparsity', the mix of zero ('fill') and non-zero values, and hence the underlying indexing.